# numpy error: ‘vectorcallfunc’ does not name a type

Tags: python, c++, numpy, cython, pybind11

Im compiling a c++ script to be used in python using Cython however, including

```
#include "numpy/ufuncobject.h"
```

returns the error message

```
In file included from Utility.cpp:764:
/usr/include/numpy/ufuncobject.h:176:9: error: ‘vectorcallfunc’ does not name a type
  176 |         vectorcallfunc vectorcall;
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I wrote a c++ script and a .pyx file to compile into a .so file using cython. My procedure goes as follows:

using the invoke package in a python file

- build the library for the c++ code

```
invoke.run(
        "g++ -O3 -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC {0} "
        "-I/usr/include/python3.10 -lpython3.10 "
        "-I {2} "
        "-o lib{1} ".format(file.cc, file.so, path_to_header_directory)
    )
```

- build the cython module

```
        invoke.run("cython --cplus -3 {0} -o {1}".format(file.pyx, file+".cpp"))
```

where file.pyx imports used

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from libcpp.string cimport string
from libcpp cimport bool
```

- then compiling the python module

```
invoke.run(

        "g++ -O3 -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC "

        "`python3 -m pybind11 --includes` "

        "-I /mnt/Data_Volume/Computer_Programs/Anaconda/envs/few_env/include/python3.7m -I . "

        "-I {2} "

        "{0} "

        "-o {1}`python3.7-config --extension-suffix` "

        "-L. -l{1} -Wl,-rpath,.".format(file.cpp, file, path_to_include_dir)

    )
```

my python and numpy versions are:

```
Python 3.7.12 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Oct 26 2021, 06:08:53) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.20.3'
```

attempting to compile using python 3.10 and using numpy version 1.23.5 doesnt change the result

Answer (score 0):

`vectorcallfunc` was introduced in Python 3.8, so this is probably a NumPy/Python headers version mismatch.

You can try to use the `-E` compiler flag to see which headers the compiler actually uses and adjust the include paths to make sure you use the version you want to use. Check out https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0029-deprecation_policy.html for a list of Python and NumPy versions that work together.